# Add new element between table rows by click on item

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `table` with some items. I would like by click on item open a list of comments to this item. 
I use `directive` for this aim and append data to my `element`. The issue is that data is appended to the right side of the `table` instead of put it between rows. I try to play with open\closing `tr` tag but it doesn't help either.

My html page:

```
<div id="content_people" ng-show="active=='people'" ng-controller="DevsListCtrl">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
        <tr feedback-holder ng-repeat="d in $data">
            <td add-new-team-member data-title='name' data-value="{{d.name}}" bs-tooltip="tooltip">{{d.name}}</td>
            <td data-title='age'>{{d.age}}</td>
            <td data-title='grade'>{{d.grade}}</td>
            <td data-title='job'>{{d.job}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My js directive:

```
mainApp.directive("feedbackHolder", ['$compile', 'teamSharedObj', function ($compile, teamSharedObj) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                console.log("Click on feedback");
                var el = angular.element('</tr><tr><div><input type="submit" value="Refresh"></div>');
                $compile(el)(scope);
                element.append(el);

            });
        }
    }
}])
```

Could you advise me a right way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert your new content between rows, use `element.after()` instead of `element.append`

> `element.after(el);`

Also the element you insert should look like this:

> `var el = angular.element('<tr><td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Refresh"></td></tr>');`

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need `colspan` like :

```
var el = angular.element('</tr><tr><td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Refresh"></td>');
```

Comment: It is expend item but content still added to the right side of the table instead of place between rows

Comment: For your next issue, to add only a single element you can move `var el = ..` before the directive return.  ex - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myJZzM?editors=101